# Og tags just stopped working

Tags: linkedin-api, thumbnails, facebook-opengraph

I have og tag images set up on my Wordpress posts, and use dlvr.it to update my clients social feeds. So basically every time I publish a post and set the correct og image, the image is pulled into the social channel that it is feeding. This has been working fine on Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn since I set it up maybe a year ago. However mid-march the LinkedIn images stopped working, they still work on Facebook and Twitter which makes this more stranger.

I have been discussing this with both dlvr and LI and both blame each other, but finally LI summarized this may be a API problem. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a LinkedIn API issue, and it goes beyond just "not showing thumbnails."

For some sites, LinkedIn accepts a link posted via the API, reports a successful post, and then the *entire post* never appears.

In dlvr.it you can change the Thumbnail Style setting for your LinkedIn Social to instruct us to pick the image instead of letting LinkedIn do it.  This may resolve the issue.

[image: Thumbnail Style]

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion, I will try it. My only concern is I have several images on the post (hence the og tag to point the social channels to the correct image to post). This way may not get the correct og image as it say: – Auto-Detected from Item Content: dlvr.it will use the first image located in the item content as the thumbnail.

Comment: However this may get the posts working as they have now stopped working! Do we know if this is a API problem or an update that has gone wrong?